# Bash cp command and quotes

Tags: regex, bash, copy, quotes, cp

i'm here for a little misunderstanding issue.

Here's what i have :

```
cp "$DIR/working-dir/shswitch_'$codesite' _ '$ip' _ '*' _ OUTPUTCONFIG" "$LOCALDIR/liste/$hostname-$ip"
```

I want to search for a file which contains words described as var, and a random number in the middle of the file's name like this :

```
shswitch_313083_126.138.36.253_**11894**_OUTPUTCONFIG
```

and copy it elsewhere.
When i'm trying this above, that's what linux says :

> cp: cannot stat `/opt/exploit/dev/florian/scan-allied/working-dir/shswitch_\'313083\'*\'126.138.36.253\'*\'*\'_OUTPUTCONFIG': No such file or directory

I don't understand why is there backslash in here, and neither why he won't search properly my file. Can you help please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper format for that is

```
cp "$DIR/working-dir/shswitch_${codesite}_${ip}_"*"_OUTPUTCONFIG" "$LOCALDIR/liste/$hostname-$ip"
```

Comment: @user2564494 Welcome. I hope you could accept the answer by clicking the check mark too thank you.